# NewRelic crash reporting not working for iOS?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have NewRelic free/beginning tier which should be OK for crash reporting.  I have installed the NewRelic agent via CocoaPods:

```
pod 'NewRelicAgent'
```

The the app startup I initialize the NewRelic agent with my app ID:

```
[NewRelicAgent startWithApplicationToken:@"AA29fa....."];
```

There is a Run Script phase in the build process (last step):

```
SCRIPT=`/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name newrelic_postbuild.sh | head -n 1`
/bin/sh "${SCRIPT}" "AA29fa......."
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

link_with 'SimpleInvoice', 'SimpleInvoiceTests'

pod 'BNHtmlPdfKit', :git => 'https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit'
pod 'DocuSign-iOS-SDK', :git => 'https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ios-sdk', :branch => 'feature_remote_signing'
pod 'VENCalculatorInputView'
pod 'NewRelicAgent'
```

I crashed the app in debugger and also published an Ad-Hoc build on TestFlight and crashed it on a device and my NewRelic shows that I don't have any crashes to report.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any other frameworks that could have registered as a crash handler? Flurry, Google Analytics, HockeyApp etc will all set themselves as a crash handler and prevent others from handling exceptions in the app. The xcode debugger will do the same so if you want to test locally you'll need to disable the debugger.

Comment: Here is my podfile: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

link_with 'SimpleInvoice', 'SimpleInvoiceTests'

pod 'BNHtmlPdfKit', :git => 'https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit'
pod 'DocuSign-iOS-SDK', :git => 'https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ios-sdk', :branch => 'feature_remote_signing'
pod 'VENCalculatorInputView'
pod 'NewRelicAgent'

Comment: TestFlight has a crash handler in it as well, if this is not disabled it would prevent NR from getting crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Test Flight includes crash reporting as well.  You need to turn off crash reporting for Test Flight, so that New Relic will be able to gather crash reports.

In your **-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** method, add the following lines of code:

```
[TestFlight setOptions:@{TFOptionReportCrashes: @NO}];
[TestFlight takeOff:@"YourTestFlightAppTokenHere"];
```